# $x \in \overline{E}$ iff $B_r(x) \cap E \neq \emptyset$. Question about proof.

Tags: general-topology

Proposition: $x \in \overline{E}$ iff $B_r(x) \cap E \neq \emptyset$

Proof: $x \in \overline{E}$ iff $x \in E \cup E'$.
In other words, $x$ has to be in either $E$ or $E'$.
If $x \in E$, then $B_r(x) \cap E \neq \emptyset$, for any $r>0$ since $x \in E$.
If $x \in E'$, then $B_r(x) \cap E -\{x\} \neq \emptyset$, for any $r>0$ by definition of a limit point.

The proof concludes by concluding that $B_r(x) \cap E \neq \emptyset$ for all $r>0$.

My question is: Why do we take the less restrictive statement to be true?

Comment: You only proved one direction of the proof.  You need to demonstrate that if $B_r(x) \cap E \neq \emptyset$ for all $r >0$ then $x \in \overline{E}$.  Additionally, can you explain what you mean by "why do we take the less restrictive statement to be true?"?  Please explain.

Comment: What's your definition of $\overline{E}$?

Comment: To me, if x∈E, then Br(x)∩E≠∅ is a less restrictive statement than if x∈E′, then Br(x)∩E−{x}≠∅.

Comment: $\overline{E}$ is the closure of E.

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition.** *$x\in\overline{E}$ if and only if, for all $r>0$, $B_r(x)\cap E\ne\emptyset$.*

According to your question, you define $\overline{E}=E\cup E'$, where $E'$ is the set of limit points of $E$.

*Proof.* $(\Rightarrow)$ If $x\in E$ we have $x\in B_r(x)\cap E$, because $x\in B_r(x)$, for any $r>0$. Suppose $x\in E'$; then, given $r>0$, $B_r(x)\cap E\ne\emptyset$ by definition of limit point.

$(\Leftarrow)$ If $x\in E$ there's nothing to prove, so we can assume that $x\notin E$. Then $x$ satisfies the definition of limit point of $E$; therefore $x\in E'$ and so $x\in\overline{E}$.

---

Note that the result is false if you interpret the given statement as “$x\in\overline{E}$ if and only if, *for some* $r>0$, $B_r(x)\cap E\ne\emptyset$”. For instance, in the reals, $2$ satisfies the condition when $E=(0,1)$ and we take $r=5$. But of course $2\notin\overline{E}$.

Answer (score 0):

We can actually prove a more general statement ($B_r(x)$ presupposes we have a metric, but a similar statement is true in all topological spaces)

Here the definiton of $\overline E$ used is: the intersection of all closed sets containing $E$. This should coincide with your definition (a good exercise for you).

**Claim**: Let $A$ be a subset of the topological space $X$. Then $x \in \overline A$ if and only if every open set $U$ containing $x$ intersects $A$.

**Proof**: Suppose that $x \in \overline A$. Suppose, by way of contradiction, that there exists an open set $U \ni x$ where $U \cap A = \emptyset$. This means that $A \subseteq X \setminus U$ which implies that $\overline A \subseteq \overline {X \setminus U} = X \setminus U$ (the latter equality is true because $U$ is open implies $X \setminus U$ is closed, and the closure of a closed set is itself). But since $x \in U$, it follows that $x \notin \overline A$, a contradiction. conclude that every open set $U$ containing $x$ intersects $A$.

Conversely, suppose that every open set $U$ containing $x$ intersects $A$. Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $x \notin \overline A$. Then $U = X \setminus \overline A$ is open, and $x \in U$. By hypothesis, $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$, but this is a contradiction to our construction of $U$ not containing $\overline A$. Conclude that $x \in \overline A$.